# Find if there is collision between two balls moving in a plane python

Tags: python, geometry, collision-detection

I have the following ball configuration:

```
P=(115,100)
T=(253,211)
C=(389,464)
r=60
```

[image]

The ball of center `C` and radius `r` follows a straight line from `C` to `P`.

In this trajectory there might be a ball `T` of radius `r` that causes a collision with ball `C` and deflects ball `C` from its course.

Ball of center `T` can be anywhere in the 2D plane except the blue region

Given `C`, `T`, `P`, and `r`, what is a clean and efficient way to detect whether or not ball `T` will interfer with ball `C` trajectory?

I would like to do this in python and other libraries can be used like numpy or pygame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can calculate distance `D` from point `T` to line `CP`.

Define vector

```
CP = P - C
```

in coordinates:

```
cpx = P.x - C.x
cpy = P.y - C.y
```

and normalize it

```
length = math.hypot(cpx, cpy)
ucpx = cpx / length
ucpy = cpy / length
```

Another vector

```
CT = T - C
ctx = T.x - C.x
cty = T.y - C.y
```

Distance using cross product

```
D = abs(CT x UCP)
D = abs(ctx*ucpy-cty*ucpx)
```

One more value - sign of dot product of vectors allows to know if `T` lies "behind" `C`

```
dtp =  (CT dot UCP)
dtp =  (ctx*ucpx+cty*ucpy)
```

Then compare `D` with radius sum (here doubled radius) and check sign of dot product

```
 if (D < 2*r) and (dtp > 0):
    collision occurs
```